# Many-to-Many insert failing - Entity Framework 4.1 DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many, dbcontext

I am using DB first method, EF 4.1 with DbContext POCO code gen.

My database has a many-to-many relationship as shown below:

**Employee**

EmployeeId

EmployeeName

**Account**

AccountId

AccountName

**EmployeeAccount**

EmployeeId

AccountId

The problem occurs when I am trying to insert a new Employee, and assign them a pre existing account, so I am basically doing this as below:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.EmployeeName = "Test";
emp.Accounts.Add(MethodThatLooksUpAccountByName("SomeAccountName"));

context.Employees.Add(emp);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The SQL this is executing (incorrectly), is attempting to INSERT a new [Account] record, and this is failing on a constraint violation. Of course, it should not INSERT a new [Account] record, it should only insert a new [EmployeeAccount] record, after inserting the [Employee].

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodThatLooksUpAccountByName` does this method return an attached or detached object? In any case, you may try to attach the object it returns to the context.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.EmployeeName = "Test";
var acc = MethodThatLooksUpAccountByName("SomeAccountName");
context.Attach(acc); //I don't remember if it's attach or attachobject, but intellisense should help you there. 
emp.Accounts.Add(acc);

context.Employees.Add(emp);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes, it's detached because I dispose of the context in the method. Your solution works fine, although the Attach() method is on the entity collection itself, not the context. Thank you, don't know how I missed this.